# Github actions && elastic benstalk deployment

Tags: github-actions, amazon-elb

I have been using AWS elastic beanstalk for a while, but  I still think that I do not 100% understand how the application versioning works. Recently I started using Github actions, and sometimes the deployments fail and the environment crashes, always the same error :

```
Error: Deployment failed: Error: Status: 400. Code: InvalidParameterValue, Message: No Application Version named 'myapp-devel-23075dfd8cf9d3ecab85f5a0a4e77bf403040a36' found.
```

I started an environment from scratch, and the current version in Elastic Beanstalk is this one:
Running version: **myapp-devel**

This is the job running on github actions:

```
name: EB deploy to myapp

on:
  push:
   branches:
      -  'myapp-devel'
    
    jobs:
      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        ## Environment variables
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
          AWS_APPLICATION_NAME: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_APPLICATION_4_NAME }}
          AWS_ENVIRONMENT_NAME:  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ENVIRONMENT_4_NAME }}
                
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v4
          - name: Install Python 3.9
            uses: actions/setup-python@v2
            with:
              python-version: 3.9
          - name: Generate deployment package
            ## create the zip
            run: zip -r  deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip . -x '*.png' -x '.gitignore' -x '/plugins/*/webroot/build/*'  -x '*.git/*' -x '*.jpeg' -x 'build/*' -x '*.webp' -x 'config-dev-server' -x '*.JPG' -x '*/node_modules/*' -x '.env_example' -x '.htaccess' -x '/plugins/*/webroot/node_modules/*' -x 'webroot/webpack-updater/*' -x '.dockerignore' -x '.vscode' -x '*.gif' -x 'tmp/*' -x 'webroot/cypress/*' -x 'Dockerfile' -x 'docker-compose.yml' -x '*/files/*' -x 'webroot/tests/*' -x '/webroot/node_modules/*' -x '*.jpg' -x 'webroot/emails/*' 
          - name: Install EB CLI using pip
            run: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install awsebcli
          - name: Upload package to S3 bucket
            run: |  
              eb init --platform 'PHP 8.2' --region  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }} ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_APPLICATION_4_NAME }}
              aws s3 --region  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }} cp deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip s3://github-action/develop/
          # - name: Create new ElasticBeanstalk Application Version on region ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
          #   run: |
          #     aws  elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
          #     --application-name  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_APPLICATION_4_NAME }} \
          #     --source-bundle S3Bucket="github",S3Key="develop/deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip" \
          #     --version-label "myapp-devel-${{ github.sha }}" \
          #     --description "commit-sha-${{ github.sha }}"
          # - name: Deploy new ElasticBeanstalk Application Version
          #   run: aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ENVIRONMENT_4_NAME }} --version-label "myapp-devel-${{ github.sha }}"
          - name: Deploy myapp-devel to EB
            uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v21
            with:
              aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
              aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
              application_name: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_APPLICATION_4_NAME }}
              environment_name: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ENVIRONMENT_4_NAME }}
              use_existing_version_if_available: true
    
              ## every deployment will be a different application versions
              version_label: myapp-devel-${{ github.sha }}
              region:  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
              deployment_package: deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip
          - name: elastic benstalk logs
            run: | 
              eb logs
```

What I should add to the version_label parameter? A different hash with each deployment? I also tried to add always the same label "myapp-devel" (without the  ${{ github.sha }}), but I still get the same error, that's why I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can debug this by:

- Checking AWS Elastic Beanstalk Console:

Log in to the AWS Management Console and navigate to Elastic Beanstalk.
Go to your environment, and in the "Versions" section, verify that the application version with the specified label (`myapp-devel-${{ github.sha }}`) exists.

- And & or manually create the version:

Uncomment the section in your workflow that creates a new Elastic Beanstalk Application Version manually using the AWS CLI.
After uncommenting, make sure to provide a unique version label for each deployment. You can use the same approach as before:

```
version-label: myapp-devel-${{ github.sha }}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, I have created a new version in ELB  with the same name, but now I get a different error, very odd: "Deployment failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VersionLabel')
"            version_label: myapp-devel-23075dfd8cf9d3ecab85f5a0a4e77bf403040a36
Why it is not able to create a new version label if the given one does not exist? I do not understand.

Comment: Uncomment the AWS CLI commands in your workflow and run them separately in a local environment. It will say if there are any issues with the commands or if the error is specific to the GitHub Actions workflow.